# Swift package manager updates on every checkout/stash

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have several SPM packages imported in my project. Every time I checkout or stash - Xcode starts "Resolving Package Graph" which lasts annoyingly long. It happens even when SPM had no changes applied between GIT operations.

Closing Xcode before performing a GIT operation helps sometimes. But having to close Xcode is still annoying.

Is there a way to prevent Xcode from triggering "Resolving Package Graph" on every checkout?

Comment: Is there any way to avoid auto-resolving package on xcode open ? Can we set it to manual process, to resolve only when dev requested.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Need to track Package.resolved in Git to resolve the issue. As long as spm package versions are the same between your git checkouts - Xcode will not trigger "Resolving Package Graph" process